# Postgres Sorting Already Sorted data in large database

Tags: python, postgresql

I am working with a postgres 10 database with billions of rows of IOT data (lets call it primary). The data is stored with a structure: SENSOR_ID, TIMESTAMP, VALUE where I use a secondary table to fetch the metadata about the sensors (lets call the table secondary).

Primary table is already stored in time order (primary key). I access the data from python code to do some simulations of an IOT environment (using the information to check streaming, models, ext). It is important that the data come out of the database in time order so to guarantee this, our queries use an ORDER BY time clause.

Because our computers cannot take billions of returns, we are trying to use a cursor and fetch small batches of results.

My issue is that for ''small'' queries (say 1 million), Postgres recognizes that the data is already in sorted order and simply does a scan on the primary index (and then does a join with the metadata secondary table) very quickly and without issue. If I give it a larger query, the QEP then includes a very expensive sort operation, despite the data not needing to be sorted.

Is there a way to get the optimizer to recognize that the data is already in order and forgo the sort when using the cursor?

For our smaller queries without cursors we can get the performance and QEPs we want but are having a hard time for larger datasets.

Two examples of QEPs and some odd issue with the optimizer. One uses a query with no limit, the other with a limit higher then the number of rows (or enough that it's trivialized).

WITHOUT LIMIT CLAUSE:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT timestampmilli, value, id, globalid FROM data11 TB1,
sensor_enrichment_11 TS WHERE TB1.id = TS.globalid AND
timestampmilli BETWEEN '2018-01-01'::timestamp AND '2018-06-06'::timestamp
ORDER BY timestampmilli;
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=99448621.97..100079863.62 rows=252496661 width=28)
   Sort Key: tb1.timestampmilli
   ->  Hash Join  (cost=1014.59..46087034.51 rows=252496661 width=28)
         Hash Cond: (tb1.id = ts.globalid)
         ->  Seq Scan on data11 tb1  (cost=0.00..42298597.84 rows=252491094 width=24)
               Filter: ((timestampmilli >= '2018-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (timestampmilli <= '2018-06-06 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
         ->  Hash  (cost=699.26..699.26 rows=25226 width=4)
               ->  Seq Scan on sensor_enrichment_11 ts  (cost=0.00..699.26 rows=25226 width=4)
```

WITH LARGE LIMIT CLAUSE:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT timestampmilli, value, id, globalid FROM data11 TB1,
sensor_enrichment_11 TS WHERE TB1.id = TS.globalid AND
timestampmilli BETWEEN '2018-01-01'::timestamp AND '2018-06-06'::timestamp 
ORDER BY timestampmilli LIMIT 10000000;
```

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.99..82250110.69 rows=10000000 width=28)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.99..2076787807.52 rows=252496661 width=28)
         ->  Index Scan using data11_pkey on data11 tb1  (cost=0.58..994786742.16 rows=252491094 width=24)
               Index Cond: ((timestampmilli >= '2018-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (timestampmilli <= '2018-06-06 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
         ->  Index Only Scan using sensor_enrichment_11_pkey on sensor_enrichment_11 ts  (cost=0.41..4.28 rows=1 width=4)
               Index Cond: (globalid = tb1.id)
```

Comment: What makes you think your data is in strict order within the table? What makes you think this is maintained after your join?

Comment: There is no constraint to force a table to always remain sorted.  An index, however, must always be sorted.  If the query is using the index but then sorting anyway, that is weird.  If it gives up on the index and uses a table seq scan, then it must sort.  Please show the plan of an offending query.